# SAPUI5 Data Binding - sap.m.Text

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

I would like to create a Text like this:

```
var content = new sap.m.Text({
    text : "{data>/User/Firstname} {data>/User/Lastname}"
})
```

But the output in the browser is just:

{data>/User/Firstname} {data>/User/Lastname}

Using:

```
var content = new sap.m.Text({
    text : "{data>/User/Firstname}"
})
```

works fine.

Comment: what does the "working" one output exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the parameter `bindingSyntax` in your loading-script and set it to `complex`
[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/0c803921b1bf4b3a97a038fbd51ef542.html)

```
data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
```

complete tag as example:

```
<script 
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
    src="/path/to/ui5/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" 
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" 
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>
```